# Rails: How to update all through ActiveRecord_Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have two related models through has_one like this:

```
class Asset
  has_one :device

class Device
  belongs_to :asset
```

I have an ActiveRecord_Relation of assets like this:

```
assets = Asset.all
```

I need to update a field in every Device for every asset.  I do NOT want to create an array of every associated device since it will be very inefficient.  I have tried things like:

```
assets.joins(:device).update_all( {:device=>{:my_field=>6} )
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't update the `Device` directly with `Device.update_all`? Are there devices that don't belong to assets?

Comment: The Asset.all is a simplified example.  In reality, the ActiveRecord_Relation is calculated through a large series of scopes based on a wide variety of search criteria.  When the search is done, I am left with 100k Asset models in an ActiveRecord_Relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is this:

```
assets = Asset.some_scope.some_other_scope
devices = Device.where("devices.asset_id IN (?)", assets.select(:id))
devices.update_all("devices.my_field=?", 6)
```

This uses a single database query to update all associated devices through their relationship with assets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL:

```
assets.joins(:device).update_all(["devices.my_field=?", 6])
```

or if that field depends on others:

```
assets.joins(:device).update_all("devices.my_field=assets.other_field")
```

Comment: Your first suggestion results in: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "devices" of relation "assets" does not exist.  It used this SQL:   UPDATE "assets" SET devices.os_id=6 WHERE "assets"."id" IN (SELECT "assets"."id" FROM "assets" INNER JOIN "devices" ON "devices"."asset_id" = "assets"."id")